# Problem with txfonts

Tags: miktex, installing, txfonts

Yesterday, I ran the update process of MikTEX 2.9. The process terminated abnormally for some reason (I don't know why) and since MikTEX was not accessible after this point (each time I ran latex the system said that some DLLs were missing). I had to reinstall MikTEX from scratch... The problem is that after this installation the following error message

```
C:\Users\amarg\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\txfonts\txfonts.sty:128: 
LaTeX Error: Too many symbol fonts declared.
```

was displayed in the log file. Furthermore, for some lines of txfonts.sty the error

```
LaTeX Error: Symbol font `largesymbolsA' not defined.
```

appeared, but I am convinced that this is caused by the previous one. These errors were not present before this new installation of MIKTEX and the txfonts package was loaded without a problem. The error does not create problems (to the best of my knowledge: I didn't notice something erroneous), but I want to resolve the issue (note, that if I comment out the line \usepackage{txfonts} the pagination of the chapter changes)... It seems that I have the latest version of txfonts package and I suppose that the MikTEX installation may have loaded an earlier version of some other package that conflicts with txfonts and causes this error. How can I handle this issue?

I have pasted the output of \listfiles below, if it helps (I compiled chapter 26)

```
*File List*
preamble.tex
memoir.cls    2016/05/16 v3.7f configurable book, report, article document class
ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifetex.sty    2011/12/15 v1.2 ifetex
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   mem10.clo    2008/01/30 v0.3 memoir class 10pt size option
mempatch.sty    2009/07/24 v6.0f Patches for memoir class v1.6180339
   babel.sty    2015/08/03 3.9m The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
 english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
   greek.ldf    2014/10/21 v1.9c Greek support for the babel system
  lgrenc.def    2013/07/16 v0.9 LGR Greek font encoding definitions
greek-fontenc.def    2013/11/28 v0.11 Common Greek font encoding definitions
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
iso-8859-7.def    2000/05/28 v1.2 Greek input encoding file
textcase.sty    2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
 silence.sty    2012/07/02 v1.5b Selective filtering of warnings and error mess
ages
  kerkis.sty    2000/02/25 v1.5 Package `kerkis.sty'
   color.sty    1999/02/16
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
   dvips.def    2014/10/14 v3.0j Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
dvipsnam.def    2014/10/14 v3.0j Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  svgnam.def    2007/01/21 v2.11 Predefined colors according to SVG 1.1 (UK)
  x11nam.def    2007/01/21 v2.11 Predefined colors according to Unix/X11 (UK)
mdframed.sty    2013/07/01 1.9b: mdframed
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
  xparse.sty    2014/11/25 v5471 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2014/11/25 v5471 L3 programming layer (loader)
expl3-code.tex    2014/11/25 v5471 L3 programming layer
    etex.sty    2015/09/02 v2.4 eTeX basic definition package (PEB,DPC)
l3unicode-data.def    2014/11/23 v5465 L3 Unicode data
 l3dvips.def    2014/11/23 v5466 L3 Experimental driver: dvips
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
zref-abspage.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module base for zref (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
md-frame-0.mdf    2013/07/01\ 1.9b: md-frame-0
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
  amsthm.sty    2015/03/04 v2.20.2
mathtools.sty    2015/06/17 v1.17 mathematical typesetting tools
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 mhsetup.sty    2010/01/21 v1.2a programming setup (MH)
 systeme.sty    2013/12/21 v0.3 Mise en forme de systemes d'equations
 xstring.sty    2013/10/13  v1.7c  String manipulations (C Tellechea)
 wrapfig.sty    2003/01/31  v 3.6
afterpage.sty    2014/10/28 v1.08 After-Page Package (DPC)
rotating.sty    2009/03/28 v2.16a rotated objects in LaTeX
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
 caption.sty    2013/05/02 v3.3-89 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2013/05/02 v1.6-88 caption3 kernel (AR)
enumitem.sty    2011/09/28 v3.5.2 Customized lists
titletoc.sty    2011/12/15 v1.6 TOC entries
pstricks.sty    2013/12/12 v0.60 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
pstricks.tex    2015/09/11 v2.63 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
  pst-fp.tex    2015/09/11 v2.63 `PST-fp' (hv)
     bbm.sty    1999/03/15 V 1.2 provides fonts for set symbols - TH
newlfont.sty    1998/08/17 v2.2m Standard LaTeX package
latexsym.sty    1998/08/17 v2.2e Standard LaTeX package (lasy symbols)
textcomp.sty    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
 upgreek.sty    2003/02/12 v2.0 (WaS)
extramarks.sty
      bm.sty    2014/10/28 v1.1c Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi)
multirow.sty
colortbl.sty    2012/02/13 v1.0a Color table columns (DPC)
    tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
     pgf.sty    2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
  pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
 type1cm.sty    2002/09/05 v0.04 BlueSky/Y&Y Type1 CM font definitions (DPC, pa
tched RF)
customStuff.tex
arydshln.sty    2004/08/31 v1.71
lettrine.sty    2015/08/31 v1.9 (Daniel Flipo)
lettrine.cfg
  cancel.sty    2013/04/12 v2.2 Cancel math terms
multicol.sty    2015/03/31 v1.8m multicolumn formatting (FMi)
 txfonts.sty    2008/01/22 v3.2.1
cntformats.sty    2014/07/20 v0.7 A different way to read counters. (CN)
cnltx-base.sty    2015/08/17 v0.13 LaTeX tools and documenting facilities (CN)
 pgfopts.sty    2014/07/10 v2.1a LaTeX package options with pgfkeys
trimspaces.sty    2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
   tasks.sty    2016/08/13 v0.12 Horizontalcolumnedlists (CN)
    epic.sty
xtemplate.sty    2014/11/25 v5471 L3 Experimental prototype document functions
 environ.sty    2014/05/04 v0.3 A new way to define environments
   tasks.cfg    2016/08/13 v0.12 tasks instances
  helvet.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (WaS)
bookInfo.tex
bookInit.tex
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
geometry.cfg
  lgrcmr.fd    2013/09/01 v1.0 Greek European Computer Regular
 omltxmi.fd    2000/12/15 v3.1
 omstxsy.fd    2000/12/15 v3.1
 omxtxex.fd    2000/12/15 v3.1
  utxexa.fd    2000/12/15 v3.1
  ts1cmr.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
  ot1txr.fd    2000/12/15 v3.1
  lgrtxr.fd
cover-large.tex
  utxsya.fd    2000/12/15 v3.1
  utxsyb.fd    2000/12/15 v3.1
  utxmia.fd    2000/12/15 v3.1
  utxsyc.fd    2000/12/15 v3.1
   blank.tex
Chapter26.tex
chapter26-cover1.eps    Graphic file (type eps)
    2601.eps    Graphic file (type eps)
  ts1txr.fd    2000/12/15 v3.1
    2602.eps    Graphic file (type eps)
    2603.eps    Graphic file (type eps)
    2604.eps    Graphic file (type eps)
    2605.eps    Graphic file (type eps)
    2606.eps    Graphic file (type eps)
table-2601.eps    Graphic file (type eps)
    2607.eps    Graphic file (type eps)
2608.eps    Graphic file (type eps)
2609.eps    Graphic file (type eps)
2610.eps    Graphic file (type eps)
2611.eps    Graphic file (type eps)
2612.eps    Graphic file (type eps)
2613.eps    Graphic file (type eps)
```

---

Comment: Off-topic: The `txfonts` package is quite ancient (even by TeX&LaTeX standards); you should give the successor packages -- `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`-- a try.

Comment: please show a small test file that shows this error, so people can debug

Comment: i can't since it is caused my specific MikTEX installation ... i will try to use the newer packages newtxtext and newtxmath as Mico suggests. I will report the result here .. thanks a lot again

Comment: what do you mean you can't? you can surely post here some small code doing `\listfiles` and report the file list from log.

Comment: I didn't know about \listings .. I pasted its output in my answer, if helps

Comment: @AthanasiosMargaris I don't think `txfonts` makes much sense with Kerkis. You should load `kmath`, instead. Also `type1cm` and `newlfont` are very obsolete and shouldn't be loaded.

Comment: @egreg: I cannot remove txfonts since the pagination is altered (I dont know why) and i will keep it for now (I will adopt your suggestion in my next book). I noticed that the problem is solved if I remove newlfont and since the removal of newlfont and type1cm does alter pagination i will remove from preable. If I undestood well in my next projects I must use newtxtext and newtxmath (as Mico suggested) as well kmath. Thanks for your answer